# .htaccess username url unless directory exists

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, vanity-url

I currently have the following code in place to give users their own URL for their username:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

However, any existing directories such as `/about/` or `/terms/` no longer work because this code has overwritten the URL.

Is there anwyay I can adjust this code to only point the URL to a profile if the file or directory doesn't already exist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25710768/1190388

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if the folder actually exists, and if so enforce a rule that does *not* redirect. If those conditions do not match, then it will continue to the rules that *do* redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The `-f` flag means it exists as a file, and `-d` means a directory. Now if the requested file actually is a file or directory it will not continue to the redirect rules

Also, you could shorten your redirect rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The `?` after the `/` means it will match with or without that character. Since the rest of the regex is unchanged this rule will tackle both cases at once.